# How to install MongoDB 3.2.3 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I am new to mongodb, cant understand how i can install MongoDB 3.2.3 in Ubuntu 14.04.

Also i have downloaded https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.2.3.tgz and extracted files from that directory, **now how i can add it with php?**

when i go to the bin directory and run mongod then this error occurs:

> vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/mongodb/mongodb/bin$ ./mongod
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.366+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8246 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.366+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.3
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.367+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b326ba835e1b70f6f31ece7937
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.367+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.367+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.367+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.367+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.367+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.368+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.368+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.368+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.384+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb- 27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.384+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
>
> 2016-02-23T16:59:47.385+0000 I -        [initandlisten]
>
> ***aborting after fassert() failure

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

we first have to import they key for the official MongoDB repository.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

After successfully importing the key you will see:

```
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Next, we have to add the MongoDB repository details so APT will know where to download the packages from.

Issue the following command to create a list file for MongoDB.

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

After adding the repository details, we need to update the packages list.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now we can install the MongoDB package itself.

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

After package installation MongoDB will be automatically started. You can check this by running the following command.

```
service mongod status
```

If MongoDB is running, you'll see an output like this (with a different process ID).

```
mongod start/running, process 1611
```

You can also stop, start, and restart MongoDB using the service commands.
To stop MongoDB use

```
service mongod stop
```

To start MongoDB use

```
service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done more easily using MongoDB apt repository:
Run these commands on the terminal as root:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.2 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
apt-get update
apt-get install mongodb-org=3.2.3 mongodb-org-server=3.2.3 mongodb-org-shell=3.2.3 mongodb-org-mongos=3.2.3 mongodb-org-tools=3.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

In your home create folder

```
mkdir mongodb

cd mongodb

curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.3.tgz

tar -xvzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.3.tgz

cd /opt 

sudo mkdir mongodb 

cd mongodb/

sudo cp -R ~/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.3/*  .
```

Dot (.) for current folder

```
cd /var/lib

sudo mkdir mongodb
```

Now try mongodb by running mongod in `opt/mongodb/bin` folder

```
cd /opt/mongodb/bin
    
sudo ./mongod --dbpath  /var/lib/mongodb
```

Comment: before do that ry searching for installed mongo packages with dpkg:

Comment: sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo

Comment: and run sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of cluttering the OS and dealing with file(dependency) management manually, try using the [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container.

1. Install [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/)
2. Start a container, listening on the default port, 27017, directly:
   `docker run --net=host --name some-mongo -d mongo`
3. You can pass all the regular `mongod` command line parameters after **-d mongo** as well as the version, i.e.:

   `docker run --net=host --name some-mongo -d mongo --storageEngine wiredTiger --smallfiles --auth ...`